# Distribution in Debian source list

Tags: debian, apt

I have been reading through the Debian documentation of the [Debian source lists](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList), and I cannot understand how packages are selected from the various distributions. For instance I have the following sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main non-free contrib
deb-src https://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main non-free contrib

deb https://security.debian.org/debian-security stable-security main contrib non-free
deb-src https://security.debian.org/debian-security stable-security main contrib non-free
```

How does APT select between versions of the same package from the `stable` and `stable-security` distributions? Could I use pinning to give priority to packages from stable security? For instance would a preference file `/etc/apt/preferences.d/priority.pref` with the content

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=stable-security
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a given package is present in multiple versions in different repositories, by default the highest version wins. Security updates always have a higher version than that in the corresponding main repository, so they are selected by default.

This is described in [`man apt_preferences`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/apt/apt_preferences.5.en.html#APT%27s_Default_Priority_Assignments):

> If two or more versions have the same priority, install the most recent one (that is, the one with the higher version number).

(By default, most repositories have the same priority.)

You could configure pinning to do this too, but you don’t need to.